# strange behavior when using Underscore when testing equals condition

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am using Underscore.js in my project and came across a weird behavior. When I filter the array with `changes_summary === 2` I am getting the desired result but when I use the same with `changes_summay === 0`, I am not getting any output.

Following is the code:

```
var result={
   "data": [
     {
      "id": 956,
      "changes_summary": 2,
      "name": "Pradeep",
      "age": 32
     },
     {
      "id": 956,
      "changes_summary": 0,
      "name": "praveen",
      "age": 22
     }
  ]
}


var filtered = _.filter(result.data, function(obj){ 
    return (obj.changes_summary && obj.changes_summary === 2)
});
//working when comparing with changes_summary with 2 but not working when comparing with 0
console.log(filtered);
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Link to Jsfiddle attached: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/2j13o0be/)

Comment: `obj.changes_summary &&` remove this to check for `0`. `0` is `falsy` See https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/2j13o0be/1/

Comment: @Tushar removing it is not *necessarily* the right thing. If the filter is only supposed to apply to objects that definitely have the property, then an additional test is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first test — `obj.changes_summary` — will fail when the property value is `0` because that's a falsy value.  If you're testing to see if the property is present in the object, you can do this:

```
return (("changes_summary" in obj) && obj.changes_summary === 0);
```

Comment: Is the `in` even needed?

Comment: @muistooshort well it depends on the intention - if the idea is to filter out objects that definitely have the property *and* for which the property value is `0`, then it's necessary.  If objects without the property should be treated as if the property value is `0`, then no.